# Having two MySQL tables, get the last result for each value of first table key

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables:

```
TABLE_01
-------------------------------
| ID         | Key1   | Key2  |
-------------------------------
| 1          | 504    | 101   |
| 2          | 504    | 102   |
| 3          | 505    | 101   |
| 4          | 505    | 103   |
| 5          | 508    | 101   |
| 6          | 510    | 104   |
| 7          | 509    | 101   |
-------------------------------
```

```
TABLE_02
----------------------------------------
| ID      | T_01 | timestamp | data    |
----------------------------------------
| 1       | 1    | ts_01     | ..abc.. |
| 2       | 1    | ts_02     | ..dfg.. |
| 3       | 2    | ts_03     | ..hij.. |
| 4       | 3    | ts_04     | ..klm.. |
| 5       | 1    | ts_05     | ..nop.. |
| 6       | 4    | ts_06     | ..qrs.. |
| 7       | 3    | ts_07     | ..tuv.. |
| 8       | 5    | ts_08     | ..wxy.. |
| 9       | 2    | ts_09     | ..z.... |
| 10      | 4    | ts_10     | ..abc.. |
----------------------------------------
```

- On both table, `ID` is the **Primary Incremental Key**
- In `TABLE_01`, the columns `key1` + `key2` are **Unique Key** (Can't be more than one `Key1 Key2` couple)
- In `TABLE_02`, the column `T_01` makes reference on `TABLE_01.ID`

---

My goal is that given a `key1` value, be able to get the last entry of `TABLE_02` for each `TABLE_01.ID` with the correspondent `timestamp` on `DESC ORDER`.

For example, if I give `505`, the output should be:

```
KEY1  |  KEY2  |  TIMESTAMP
---------------------------
505   |  103   |  ts_10          ---> FROM TABLE_01.Id = 4
505   |  101   |  ts_07          ---> FROM TABLE_01.Id = 3
```

As you can see, It only shows the last entry on the case of `TABLE_01.ID = 4` (which is 505 | 103)

I have tried to do something like this:

```
SELECT `t1`.`Key1`, `t1`.`key2`, `t2`.`timestamp` 
FROM `TABLE_02` AS t2 
INNER JOIN `TABLE_01` AS t1 
WHERE `t1`.`key1` = '505' 
ORDER BY `t2`.`ID` 
DESC LIMIT 100
```

The problem with this query is that since I am using `t2.timestamp`, I am receiving all the results instead of only ONE for EACH. Also, I'm not using correctly the `TABLE_01.ID` on `TABLE_02`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the latest timestamp in the second table per combination of keys in the first table, you can join and aggregate:

```
select t1.key1, t1.key2, max(t2.timestamp) max_t2_timestamp
from table_01 t1
inner join table_02 t2 on t2.t_01 = t1.id
group by t1.key1, t1.key2
```

If you want the entire row of the second table, then I would recommend window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t1.key1, t1.key2, t2.*,
        row_number() over(partition by t1.key1, t1.key2 order by t2.timestamp desc) rn
    from table_01 t1
    inner join table_02 t2 on t2.t_01 = t1.id
    group by t1.key1, t1.key2
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much! From the second table, I just need the `timestamp`, the other important data is from the first table (`Key2`). Is it possible that the first query, misses the condition of `key1 = value`? I have tried to add a `WHERE t1.key = value` after `from table_01 t1`.. But it seems it doesn't work like this.

Comment: I have managed to "fix it". With your permission, I will edit the answer to be able to mark it as an Accepted answer. Thank you very much for this! Really appreciate it.